# RSS feed not populating Facebook instant articles

Tags: facebook-instant-articles

Any ideas why the rss feed (http://facebook.moiraecreative.co.uk/facebook-test) is not populating either my production or development feed with any articles. all help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You have not formatted as per Facebook guidelines.
Have a look at this: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instant-articles/reference/

As per guidelines issued by Facebook, your code is not appropriate. It should contain the following code.

```
<content:encoded>
        <![CDATA[
        <!doctype html>
        <html lang="en" prefix="op: http://media.facebook.com/op#">
          <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8">
            <link rel="canonical" href="http://example.com/article.html">
            <meta property="op:markup_version" content="v1.0">
          </head>
          <body>
            <article>
              <header>
                <!— Article header goes here -->
              </header>

              <!— Article body goes here -->

              <footer>
                <!— Article footer goes here -->
              </footer>
            </article>
          </body>
        </html>
        ]]>
      </content:encoded>
```